# Position of a container

Tags: html, css

I have a container that I want to leave fixed on the page, to follow the scrolling of the page,
so i put position:relative, and it worked as i wanted,
but now i just made the page footer and the container overlaps the footer when i scroll the page to the end, i read that using position: sticky maybe solves the problem, but when I use the sticky property it just doesn't work. So if someone help me find a solution to solve this either using sticky or javascript, I would be very grateful.

```css
/* Gerais */

* {
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

html,body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color:  #545454;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.primary-bg-color {
    background-color: #545454;
}

.secondary-bg-color {
    background-color: #46484B;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFC85D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s;
    width: auto;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #FFC85D;
    border-color: #FFC85D;
}

.btn-secondary {
    background-color: #FFC85D;
    color: #1E1E1E;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: .5s;
    width: 20rem;
}

.btn-secondary:hover {
    background-color: #EDC77A;
    border-color: #EDC77A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Navbar */

#navbar {
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

.logo {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-brand { 
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
}

#logo-img {
    height: 6rem;
    width: auto;
}

#navbar-items {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    min-width: 80%;
}

#navbar .navbar-nav {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#navbar .navbar-nav li {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar .nav-link {
    display: flex;
}

#navbar .nav-link i {
    color: #FFC85D;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: .5rem;
}

#navbar .nav-link .bi-person-circle {
    font-size: 60px;
}

#navbar a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: .5s;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    color: #FFC85D;
}

#search-form, #news-form {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #626262;
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5rem;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    width: 40%;
}

#search-form i, #news-form i { 
    color: #FFC85D;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#search-form input, #news-form input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#search-form input:focus, #news-form input:focus{
    box-shadow: none;
}

#search-form input::placeholder, #news-form input::placeholder {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Jogos */

.container-fluid h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Carousel */

.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
    height: 80%;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    height: 80%;
}

/* Sobre */

.container-fluid h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container-fluid p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Especificações */

#windows, #linux, #macos {
    display: none;
}

#especificacoes img {
    height: 1rem;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

#especificacoes nav {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#especificacoes nav .slider {
    background-color: #46484B;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 33.33%;
    z-index: 0;
}

#especificacoes label {
    align-items: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#linux:checked ~ nav .slider {
    left: 33.33%;
}

#macos:checked ~ nav .slider {
    left: 66.66%
}

.content {
    display: none;
}

.content span {
    color: #1E1E1E;
}

#windows:checked ~ section .content-1, #linux:checked ~ section .content-2, #macos:checked ~ section .content-3 {
    display: block;
}

.especificacoes-min {
    border-right: 2.5px solid #1E1E1E;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.especificacoes-rec {
    border-left: 2.5px solid #1E1E1E;
    padding: 1rem;
}

/* Infos */

.right {
    right: 0;
    height: fit-content;
}

.container-fluid h3 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1E1E1E;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.jogos {
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.jogo {
    width: auto;
}

.jogo img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.jogo p {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #A5C400;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    color: #1E1E1E;
    display: flex;
    height: 3rem;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: -3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

.infos {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.infos p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: .5rem;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

.infos img {
    height: 2rem;
    margin-left: .5rem;
    margin-right: .5rem;
    width: 2rem;
}

/* Footer */

#footer-links-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFC85D;
}

#footer .footer-column {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-left, #footer-center, #footer-right {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFC85D;
}

#footer-center {
    border-left: 1px solid #FFC85D;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFC85D;
}

#footer .footer-column {
    padding: 2rem;
}

#footer-links-container h3 {
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 0;
}

#footer-links-container li {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-links-container a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .5s;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#footer-links-container a:hover {
    color: #FFC85D;
}

#newsletter-container {
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFC85D;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#news-form {
    margin: 15px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}

#news-form i {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#news-form .btn {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#social-container {
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#social-container i {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 10px;
    transition: .5s;
}

#social-container i:hover {
    color: #FFC85D;
}

#copy-container {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#copy-container p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Scrollbar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1rem;
}
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #1E1E1E;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #FFC85D;
}

/* Responsividade */

@media (max-width: 1300px) {

    .logo {
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-right: .5rem;
    }

    #logo-img, .navbar-brand {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jogos</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-2 px-2" id="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid px-0">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo-img">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-items">
                    <form class="d-flex" id="search-form">
                        <i class="bi bi-search primary-color"></i>
                        <input type="search" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Digite aqui a sua pesquisa..." aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link ">Comunidade<i class="bi bi-chat"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link">Devs<i class="bi bi-lightbulb"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link">Games<i class="bi bi-controller"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex mt-4 mb-4">
            <div class="container-fluid col-7 m-0">
                <h1 class="mb-4">Enter the Gungeon</h1>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators">
                            <button class="active" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 3"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 4"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 5"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-current="true" aria-label="slide 6"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <video src="/img/slider1.webm" type="video/webm" alt="" class="d-block w-100" autoplay muted controls></video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="/img/slider2.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="/img/slider3.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="/img/slider4.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="/img/slider5.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="/img/slider6.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
                        <h2>Sobre esse jogo</h2>
                        <p>Enter the Gungeon é uma aventura em um labirinto com armas de fogo, na qual um bando de desajustados arrependidos terá que atirar, saquear, se esquivar e virar mesas, em busca da absolvição pessoal, chegando ao lendário tesouro final do Balabirinto: a arma que mata o passado.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid mt-4 mb-4" id="especificacoes">
                        <h3>Especificações</h3>
                        <input type="radio" name="slider" checked id="windows">
                        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="linux">
                        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="macos">
                        <nav class="d-flex mb-4">
                            <label for="windows" class="windows"><img src="/img/plataforma1.png" alt="">Windows</label>
                            <label for="linux" class="linux"><img src="/img/plataforma2.png" alt="">Linux</label>
                            <label for="macos" class="macos"><img src="/img/plataforma3.png" alt="">MacOS</label>
                            <div class="slider"></div>
                        </nav>
                        <section>
                            <div class="content content-1">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
                                    <li class="especificacoes-min">
                                        <p>Mínimos:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> Windows 7 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Processador:</span> Intel Core 2 Duo E6320 (2*1866) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Placa de vídeo:</span> GeForce 7600 GS (512 MB) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="especificacoes-rec">
                                        <p>Recomendados:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> Windows 7 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Processador:</span> Intel Core 2 Duo E6320 (2*1866) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Placa de vídeo:</span> GeForce 7600 GS (512 MB) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content content-2">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
                                    <li class="especificacoes-min">
                                        <p>Mínimos:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> Ubuntu 12.04 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Processador:</span> Intel Core 2 Duo E6320 (2*1866) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Placa de vídeo:</span> GeForce 7600 GS (512 MB) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="especificacoes-rec">
                                        <p>Recomendados:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> Ubuntu 12.04 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Processador:</span> Intel Core 2 Duo E6320 (2*1866) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Placa de vídeo:</span> GeForce 7600 GS (512 MB) ou equivalente</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content content-3">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
                                    <li class="especificacoes-min">
                                        <p>Mínimos:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> OS 10.6 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="especificacoes-rec">
                                        <p>Recomendados:</p>
                                        <p><span>SO:</span> OS 10.6 ou posterior</p>
                                        <p><span>Memória:</span> 2GB de RAM</p>
                                        <p><span>Armazenamento:</span> 2GB de espaço disponível</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <! -- Container -->
            <div class="container-fluid col-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center position-fixed right">
                <div class="row d-flex flex-column m-2">
                    <div class="col d-flex flex-column jogos mb-4">
                        <div class="col d-flex flex-column jogo">
                            <img src="/img/jogo.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                            <p>7+</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between secondary-bg-color mb-2 infos"><p>Desenvolvedor</p><p>Dogge Roll</p></div>
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between secondary-bg-color mb-2 infos"><p>Destribuidora</p><p>Devolver Digital</p></div>
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between secondary-bg-color mb-2 infos"><p>Data de Lançamento</p><p>05/Abr./2016</p></div>
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between secondary-bg-color mb-4 infos">
                        <p>Plataformas</p>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <img src="/img/plataforma1.png" alt=""><img src="/img/plataforma2.png" alt=""><img src="/img/plataforma3.png" alt="">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Jogar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="footer-links-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 footer-column" id="footer-left">
                    <h3>Rmax</h3>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Diretizes do Site</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 footer-column" id="footer-center">
                    <h3>Informações</h3>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Politíca de Cookies</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Politíca de Privacidade</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Termos e Condições</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 footer-column" id="footer-right">
                    <h3>Para desenvolvedores</h3>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Ajude Desenvolvedores</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">APIs de Games</a></li>
                        <li class="mb-2"><a href="">Programa de Parceria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="newsletter-container">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <p>Se inscreva na nossa Newletter:</p>
                    <form class="d-flex" id="news-form">
                        <i class="bi bi-envelope primary-color"></i>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Insira o seu E-mail">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12" id="social-container">
                <i class="bi bi-github"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-youtube"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="copy-container">
            <p>Copyright © 2022 | Rmax. Todos os direitos reservados</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I left a comment where the container's HTML starts, and the CSS of the container is in the part of /* Infos */

Z-index works but it gets a little weird [image]

it would be perfect if the container arrived at the footer and stopped moving, I think it could be done with JS but I have no idea how
[image]

Comment: you need to add z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: It solves the problem but a part still appears and it's kind of weird, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I see `<p>7+<p>` overlapping a section of the header. Do you want this behavior? About your question, I think you'd be closer to what you intend using `.right-container { position: sticky; }`.

Comment: "Z-index works, but it gets a little weird." How does it work? Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do. If you can share a pic of your final design, it'd be very helpful.

Comment: The 7 would be an indicative rating but there is no game image in the snippet, I added an image of how it turned out with the z-index, it hides a part but not all and it looks a little weird

Comment: I preferably wanted the container to stop descending when it reached the footer or to disappear completely

Comment: Please, could you make your question more explicit? It will be more helpful to others with similar issues. You could try something like "How to keep container within viewport while scrolling down?". Check `position: -webkit-sticky!important;`. Also, try not to use `!important`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the container into viewport using:

```
.target-container {
  position: sticky;
  
  //This is the offset from the top of the screen. Change it accordingly.
  top: 2rem;
}
```

Note that:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

will prevent `position: sticky` from working.

Comment: Thank you very much Pedro, Only the position: sticky solved the problem. Now the container only scrolls to the end of the div, I don't even need to use z-index or JavaScript

Comment: If you want to see how it turned out, https://rmax.tk/

Comment: That’s great! I thought we’ll have to use: `Now we have to check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page (I'll use JavaScript and the Intersection Observer API). Then we'll move it to the bottom of the parent container, which uses display: flex, setting the margin-top of the target-container to auto.`. But looking at the result I’ll delete that section.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your sticky menu hides under your footer (not overlapping it)
use this code for your footer

```
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It solves the problem but a part still appears and it's kind of weird, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I think it would be better to stick the container until it reaches the footer, then let it go up with the whole page. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Yes I wanted to do that too but I have no idea how, I think it can be done using JS but I haven't learned JS yet